# I have a type defined object and I want to declare a variable and then assign a value to the keys

Tags: javascript, typescript, javascript-objects, typescript-generics

I have been working on typescript for the last 4 months only, I am a kinda newbie, and need help.
Here is the type definition I am going to use as inferred type.

```js
export type InputFileId = {
  fileId: string;
  rate?: 'satisfied' | 'investigation' | 'wrong' | 'none';
};
export type UserData= {
  uId: string;
};
export type UpdateResponseObject = {
  calculationName?: string;
  temperatureC?: number,
  isLoadChange?: boolean,
  loadN?: number;
  projectId?: string;
  ownersIds?: Array<UserData>;
  fileId?: Array<InputFileId>;
};
```

Here is what I want to achieve.

```js
const responseData: UpdateResponseObject[] = [];
```

Now I want to use it as follows

```js
let fileIdArray: any[] = [];
```

I want to send a response of type `UpdateResponseObject` and to do so I want to populate the keys/data as defined in the type definition.

```js
responseData.fileId = fileIdArray;
```

Maybe edit the question or change it or maybe I am stupid.

Comment: `I want to send a response of type UpdateResponseObject and to do so I want to populate the keys/data as defined in the type definition` Could you explain this more clearly with some examples ?